# enable download button for html5 audio player in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

I have an audio element on a page that is added dynamically using javascript in the dom.

The outputted html is such:

```
        <audio preload="auto" controls="controls">
            <source src="https://urlofmp3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
```

when I view this audio element on the page it looks like this:
[image: html5 audio tag]

As I understand Chrome is supposed to automatically put a download button on the right hand side... but for whatever reason it's not there. I've been able to find lots of sites telling me how to turn the download button off, but is there a way to explicitly turn it on?

Comment: Do you have `nodownload` showing in the audio.controlsList..? If it does you may try `auido.controlsList.remove('nodownload');`

Comment: I haven't explicitly added nodownload to the controls list anywhere but I'll try adding this line to see what happens.

Comment: No luck, same symptoms as before...

Comment: You should post a working example, I think it might have todo with the file size of the MP3. Where Chrome fails to create a downloadable file out of it.

Comment: unfortunately whenever this comes up its in our app using proprietary client recordings. so I can't put those on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const audio = `<audio preload="auto" controls="controls">
                  <source 
                    src="https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"                           type="audio/mp3">
              </audio>`;
document.getElementById('song').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', audio);
```

```html
<div id="song"></div>
```

If you put a real MP3 file as src is showing the download button even adding the `audio` element dinamically with Javascript. I suppose that it checks and preloads the file and when *success* fills the controls...

Comment: while my example code above has 'urlofmp3.mp3' thats just a generification of what I'm using in production, as the mp3 files on production are client data. I can assure you that they are real files that do play without issue.

Answer (score -1):

i had the the same problem. i finally found a solution for this.

at first i just tried to let it download the `.ogg` `.wav` or `.mp3` file this made it open in another tab in my browser but did not let me download it. now i treid to put the `.ogg`file into a zip folder and try to let it download the folder which was the solution for my froblem.

the code i use for this:

```
<button>
    <a href="HooniganProds\songs.zip" download>Click to Download!</a>
    </button>
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble following exactly what you did here, can you clarify? how did the files play if they were zipped?

Comment: I downvoted your answer as it is not related to the question "enable download button for html5 audio player in chrome". There's no audio player involved in your response/example.